# Onclick text disappears in chrome but not in mozilla

Tags: textbox, full-text-search, onclick, cross-browser

I have search functionality in my app, in which when user clicks in textbox, 
  the text in the text box disappers. This works perfectly in chrome(6.0) but does not disappear after click in mozilla firefox(3.6) why?

// here is the code:

```
echo "Search: ";
            echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"smalltxt\" name= \"srchtxt\" id= \"srchtxt\" value= \"enter username\" height=\"20px\" onfocus= \"javascript:areaOnFocus(srchtxt, 'enter username');\" onblur= \"javascript:areaOnBlur(srchtxt, 'enter username');\" />";
```

// function called:

```
function areaOnFocus(element, inputText)
    {
         if(element.value == inputText)
         {
              element.value='';
         }
    }

    function areaOnBlur(element, inputText)
    {
         if(element.value=='')
         {
              element.value = inputText;
         }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify which of the two behaviours you are expecting? (ie which browser is getting it wrong?). And please provide a bit of code so that we can make some sensible suggestions rather than having to guess. Also, have you tested in any other browsers? What were the results?

Comment: @Spudley text in the textbox disappears onclick in chrome but doesnot in mozilla. added code. no I have not tested it other browsers.

Comment: Please look at my edit below. It seems you've done something wrong, because my solution works for me in Firefox 3.6.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need `javascript:` in the inline event handlers.
Secondly, try to pass `this` instead of `srchtxt` as the first argument for both functions.
Passing just `srchtxt` probably causes the browser to find the element with the specified `name`, but this doesn't work in Firefox if I remember well.
The final code should look like this:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"smalltxt\" name= \"srchtxt\" id= \"srchtxt\" value= \"enter username\" height=\"20px\" onfocus= \"areaOnFocus(this, 'enter username');\" onblur= \"areaOnBlur(this, 'enter username');\" />";
```

**EDIT:** @down: this is impossible, because I've tried the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function areaOnFocus(element, inputText)
{
    if(element.value == inputText)
    {
        element.value='';
    }
}

function areaOnBlur(element, inputText)
{
    if(element.value=='')
    {
        element.value = inputText;
    }
}
</script>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="smalltxt" value="enter username" height="20px" onfocus="areaOnFocus(this, 'enter username');" onblur="areaOnBlur(this, 'enter username');" />
</body>
</html>
```

in my Firefox 3.6.10 and it worked well - when the page has loaded, the input's value was "enter username". When I clicked it, the text disappeared. And when I left the field empty and removed the focus, "enter username" appeared again in it. So...

Comment: I am really confused too because it works when i does it in separate file, but just getting this issue in main file. can you suggest something?

Comment: Hmm... what about the error console? Are there any logs inside?

Comment: I am glad I could help you. P.S.If you've accepted the answer, you may also vote it up :)